# VBA - How to use ShellExecute?

Tags: vba, shell, excel, cmd

I'm trying to  get the computer to sleep through excel VBA. For that to happen I need to disable hybernation which can only be done with elevated permissions. So I'm trying ShellExecute - following Microsoft's instructions on [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170918), but I'm getting an runtime error ('49' Bad DLL calling convention).

Edit:
Changed the code and it works now, but the parameters are incorrect.

```vb
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                                                             ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                                             ByVal lpszOp As String, _
                                                             ByVal lpszFile As String, _
                                                             ByVal lpszParams As String, _
                                                             ByVal lpszDir As String, _
                                                             ByVal FsShowCmd As Long) as long
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL as long = 1
Sub DoSleep()
    ShellExecute 0, "runas", "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe", "powercfg -h off", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
    Shell "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0"
    ShellExecute 0, "runas", "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe", "powercfg -h on", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you define `SW_SHOWNORMAL`?

Comment: Add `As Long` to the end of the declaration. You're returning a `Variant` because you haven't specified the return type so it doesn't match the function declaration in the DLL.

Comment: Added as long and it now runs without the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the definition of `SW_SHOWNORMAL`. The way you have defined it assumes it is an `Integer` (default for VBA which is a 16 bit value) where it needs to be `Long` (32 bit value).

Change your declaration to this:-

`Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1`

Comment: Not necessary. It will get cast to a long based on the function declaration.

Comment: Declared it as a long and still got the same error.

Comment: I think @Bond got it right.  You have not defined the return type `As Long` at the end of your `Declare` statement.  Well spotted. +1 for you...

Comment: @jony I suggest you start another question for the new problem.

Comment: Please upvote @Bond for his answer via comment so future visitors will get the benefits.

Comment: He needs to post an answer so that I can do that. (Is another way to upvote him?)

Comment: You can upvote the comment.  It is up to him if he wants to repost it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I had never noticed that elusive feature!

Answer (score 0):

Your lpszDir parameter is incorrect. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea:
If lpFile specifies an executable file, this parameter is a pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the parameters to be passed to the application. The format of this string is determined by the verb that is to be invoked. If lpFile specifies a document file, lpParameters should be NULL.

You should change this line:

```
ShellExecute 0, "runas", "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe", "powercfg -h off", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

to:

```
ShellExecute 0, "runas", "powercfg", "-h off","C:\Windows\System32", SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

This is my result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0OrR.png

Comment: Not only did you quote the rules for a wrong parameter (`lpParameters` instead of `lpDirectory`), but the `lpFile` also does specify "an executable file", so even if those rules actually applied (which they don't), the OP's code would be correct in passing the `"C:\"`. You cannot just omit a non-optional parameter with `,,` either.